# Should we provide dedicated servers for our mobile multiplayer game?

Tags: android, ios, networking

We are developing a synchronous multiplayer game. As it stands one of the players is selected as the server instead of connecting the clients to a dedicated server.

With the restricted environment of mobile apps, should we still be worried about cheating (from the player running the server) or is this a non issue in the mobile space? Are there any other major concerns we should look out for if we decide to stick with players hosting the game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the below is about Android. iOS is more secure, but the server load issue still applies there too.

If you store game data on the SD card, any app can access that data. You could encrypt it, but it would still be a liability (like the Whatsapp hack here: techcrunch.com/2014/03/12/hole-in-whatsapp-for-android-lets-hackers-steal-your-conversations/)

If someone were to implement a low-level interception / modification of your game server network traffic, this could also be a problem. (http://www.justbeck.com/modifying-data-in-transit-to-android-apps-using-burp-and-backtrack-5/)

If you are using a Service, make sure it's a local service so it's only accessible from your app.

Also, the "restricted" aspect of Android systems can be easily removed by rooting the device.

Another thing to consider is network and cpu load. Both these things could grow big very fast, making the server laggy or even crash, considering the relatively low capacities of Android devices as compared to dedicated servers. Of course, this depends on the amount of work the server has to do per client.

In general, dedicated servers are a good idea, even for Android games I think.

Answer (score 1):

I'd look into this from two different point of views:

1. Cost/Benefit: have in mind that dedicated server will impact your budget, so ask yourself if cheating is really a concern or not. I'd treat mobile space as other kind of spaces.
2. Game quality: As #1 is your point of view, this is your players point of view... They are going to feel something is going wrong and think about cheating? maybe. You can fix this with a reputation of the player that is hosting the server.